# Get/Read email message and output plain text

Tags: python, gmail, imapi

On `Windows OS` using `Python 2.7` and `Gmail` - trying to fetch and read email's body.

```
# Parse the email message
msg = email.message_from_string(msg_data[0][1].decode('UTF-8'))

# Extract the "FROM" field
from_field = msg['FROM']

# Extract the received timestamp
received_timestamp = msg['Date']

msg_body = None
# Extract the body of the email
if msg.is_multipart():
    for part in msg.walk():
        # if part.get_content_type() == 'text/html':
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
            msg_body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
            break
else:
    msg_body = msg.get_payload(decode=True).decode()


# Print the results
print('FROM: {}'.format(from_field))
print('Received: {}'.format(received_timestamp))
print('Body:\n{}'.format(msg_body))
```

I am able to print `"from_field"` and `"received_timestamp"` variables - so I know its hitting the right email/message id.

I tried `"text/html"` - this gives me nice HTML format of the email (but I want it in plain text) and I tried `"text/plain"` this gives me `"None"`.

I guess I don't have to use `"beautifulsoup"` or `"re"` to do fetch plain text.

I searched this forum and attempted to understand existing posts, but was not able to figure out what is missing in my code.

Any hints or pointers would be helpful - Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, if it's in HTML format, you would just need to convert to plain text, right?

Comment: Or how would [`as_string()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.compat32-message.html#email.message.Message.as_string) work?

Comment: The html2text library should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `msg.get_payload()` instead of `msg.get_payload(decode=True).decode()`. The `get_payload()` method should return the plain text content without requiring additional decoding.

If that doesn't work but `text/html` is giving you the html, then maybe you can use python's built-in `html` library to extract that.  Something like

```py
html_body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
            msg_body = html.unescape(html_body).replace('\r', '').replace('\n', ' ')
```

should work.